# Django South DatabaseError: App inside app - Table doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-south, django-cms

After being inspired by django-oscar, I tried to put a cmsplugin inside its main app. However, after doing a `schemamigration --initial` I can't use the plugin in Django CMS.

```
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'devel_test.cmsplugin_galleries_gallerycontainer_galleries' doesn't exist")
```

### App Tree

- gallery

  - apps

    - cmsplugin_galleries

      - migrations
      - cms_plugins.py
      - **init**.py
      - models.py
    - **init**.py
  - migrations
  - static
  - templates
  - admin.py
  - **init**.py
  - models.py
  - views.py

### Gallery models

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'title'), max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(_(u'description'), blank=True)
    image_folder = FilerFolderField(verbose_name=_(u'image folder'))
    is_video = models.BooleanField(_(u'is video content'), default=False)
    snippet = models.TextField(_(u'video snippet'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u'Gallery')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Galleries')

class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, verbose_name=_(u'gallery'))
    title = models.CharField(_(u'title'), max_length=200, blank=True)
    src = FilerImageField(verbose_name=_(u'image'))
```

### Cmsplugin_galleries models

```
class GalleryContainer(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(_(u'title'), max_length=200)
    galleries = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery, verbose_name=_(u'galleries'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

Since I can properly run it using `syncdb --all`, what did I do wrong?

**Notes:**
Using `syncdb` creates a table with the name `cmsplugin_galleries_gallerycontainer_galleries` but using *south*, the table name is `cmsplugin_gallerycontainer_galleries`

Thanks

Comment: it's probably a bug: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1314

Comment: Are you using django cms 3.0? If yes be sure to upgrade to newest develop branch

Comment: No, I'm using django cms 2.4.3 and south 0.8.4. I wonder if there's an alternative to daigorocub's link. Manually changing the migrations sounds nasty but if there's no other choice I guess I'll have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no other alternative I followed @daigorocub tip and replaced all the shorten_name instances of `cmsplugin_gallerycontainer_galleries` inside the migration file

```
m2m_table_name = db.shorten_name(u'cmsplugin_gallerycontainer_galleries')
```

to

```
m2m_table_name = db.shorten_name(u'cmsplugin_galleries_gallerycontainer_galleries')
```

This issue was fixed in the development branch of django cms 3.0 (https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2291#ref-pullrequest-26529456) but since my version is older I couldn't update to the latest branch

Thank you guys for your help!